# NVIDIA Driver causing the resolution to be fixed in 1024x768 and takes a lot of time to load desktop after login

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 22.04, display-resolution, syslinux

Letely i've been facing a trouble with my nvidia driver no matter the driver that i choose(even the nouveau) the resolution always get stuck at 1024x768 (or 800x600 if i use a 22" monitor)
[[my display settings]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wC96l.png)
and also it takes a lot of time after the login to show the desktop.
I've tried a lot of solutions like downloading every driver that is compatible with my gpu (gtx 1650 super) using apt and from the nvidia website or the software update panel

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Your question as written suggests that you have two unrelated issues: a video driver issue and a slow boot time. You might be better served splitting these two issues into their own questions.